# Fetch vs Axios review?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, fetch

I'm currently learning how to use axios and fetch api. I'm trying to make a request using a fetch api like this:

```
    let response = await fetch('https://online.yoco.com/v1/charges/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'X-Auth-Secret-Key': process.env.SECRET_KEY,
        },
        body: {
            token: paymentToken,
            amountInCents: 2799,
            currency: 'ZAR' 
        }
      });
      let responseData =  await response.json()
```

And an axios post request like this:

```
axios.post(
  'https://online.yoco.com/v1/charges/',
  {
    token: 'tok_test_DjaqoUgmzwYkwesr3euMxyUV4g',
    amountInCents: 2799,
    currency: 'ZAR',
  },
  {
    headers: {
      'X-Auth-Secret-Key': SECRET_KEY,
    },
  },
)
.then(res => {
//code
})
.catch(error => {
  // handle errors
})
```

Is the request the same or not?
Cause the fetch returns an error

Comment: *"Cause the fetch returns an error"* ***What*** error?

Answer (score 0):

No, those aren't the same, in two ways:

1. If you look at MDN's documentation for `fetch`, you'll see that it says this about [`body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#body):

   > **`body`**
   >
   > Any body that you want to add to your request: this can be a `Blob`, an `ArrayBuffer`, a `TypedArray`, a `DataView`, a `FormData`, a `URLSearchParams`, string object or literal, or a `ReadableStream` object. This latest possibility is still experimental; check the compatibility information to verify you can use it. Note that a request using the GET or HEAD method cannot have a body.

   Notice that a plain object is not on that list.
2. You're not checking for HTTP errors. This is unfortunately a footgun in the `fetch` API (I wrote about it [here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html)): It only rejects its promise on *network* errors, not HTTP errors like 404.

I'm going to assume that your API accepts JSON. If so, you need to include the `Content-Type` header and call `JSON.stringify`:

```
let response = await fetch("https://online.yoco.com/v1/charges/", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "X-Auth-Secret-Key": process.env.SECRET_KEY,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",             // ***
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({                              // ***
        token: paymentToken,
        amountInCents: 2799,
        currency: "ZAR",
    }),                                                 // ***
});
if (!response.ok) {                                     // ***
    throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);   // ***
}                                                       // ***
let responseData = await response.json();
```